# Using $lookup from different collections on condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 collections drivers, users and dispatchers. Dispatcher can be driver or user my dispatchers collection is like this,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c9bb56a56f1a43e8aedf3c1"),
"dispatcherId" : ObjectId("5c3382fe3406281ba6863f7e"),
"type" : "driver",
"recordedTime" : ISODate("2019-03-27T17:39:54.030Z"),
"isEnable" : true,
"dispatchPackageType" : "commission",
"__v" : 0
}
```

dispatcherId is from drivers or users collections. type is 'driver' or 'user'. 
I want to write a query if type is 'driver' $lookup from drivers if type is user $lookup from 'users'. I implemented this but I could not find a method to check the condition.

```
Dispatcher.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        'type': 'driver'
    }
},{
            $lookup: {
                from: "drivers",
                localField: "dispatcherId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "dispatcherDetails"
            }
        }, {
            $project: {
                'dispatcherDetails.otpPin': 0,
                'dispatcherDetails.saltSecret': 0,
                'dispatcherDetails.otpTime': 0
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Currently it is not possible to implement this functionality using lookup but if you want to do you can do that using mongoose populate method. If you fine with mongoose lemme know I will post the answer

Comment: @PavanVora Thanks for replying, if u have any answer please post it.

Comment: `dispatcherId` is the common field from the `users` and `drivers` collection. Am I right?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yes it is _id field form drivers or users

Comment: You probably should look at [Discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) in the mongoose documentation. Instead of actually having different "physical collections", this basically puts things in the same collection with a `__t` field representing the "type". It's basically polymorphism as you can abstract different schema and methods as "objects" and they appear as different models, but are in fact stored in the same collection. From the "MongoDB point of view" a `$lookup` is basically done on the "single collection" and filtered ( if needed ) by "type", or not for both.

Comment: I have posted an answer for exactly what you are asking for if you have any doubt please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use the `refType` option of mongoose schema. I try to explain you `refType` using the example.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const dispatcherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: { type: String, enum: ["User", "Driver"] },
  dispatcherId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, refPath: "type" }
});
const Dispatcher = mongoose.model("Dispatcher", dispatcherSchema);


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);


const driverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    drivername: String
});
const Driver = mongoose.model('Driver', driverSchema);

// Dispatcher.find().populate('dispatcherId'); this is just for your reference
```

Here we have three collections `'User'`, `'Driver'` and `'Dispatcher'`. Now when you do mongoose query with `populate('dispatcherId')` it will take the dispatcherId field from dispatcher document and match the dispatcherId value with the collection User or Driver based on the value stored in type field.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. How can project the fields which are needed?

Comment: refPath: "userType" should be refPath: "type" isn't it?

Comment: @Chathura yes refPath will be equal type. and to project the fields which are needed use can pass the second parameter as string in populate method like .populate('dispatcherId', 'username'). To select more items pass the space separated string like for email and phone pass second paramerter as 'email phone' in populate method